# Cannot bulk load. The file "'+ @imagepath +'" does not exist or you don't have file access rights

Tags: sql, sql-server, file-upload

I'm trying to insert an image in SQL server but I got this error :

> Cannot bulk load. The file "'+ @imagepath +'" does not exist or you don't have file access rights.

```
Create procedure insert_test
AS
BEGIN
INSERT test(
   Id,
logo

)
     VALUES (
         @Id,
(SELECT  BulkColumn
    FROM Openrowset(Bulk '''+ @imagepath +''', Single_Blob) as img),
END
```

Execution code

```
EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[test_insert]
    @Id = N'0001',
    @imagepath = 'D:\\heart.png',

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value

GO
```

How can I fix this error?

**Update :**

This is an example of the procedure that I have created to use it:

```
USE [SysTest]
GO


ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[userinformations_insert]
@UserId nvarchar(55),
@UserName nvarchar(max),
@UserPhone int ,
@UserAdress int,
@UserEmail nvarchar(50),
@imagepath nvarchar(100),


AS
BEGIN

IF EXISTS ( SELECT 1 from User)
BEGIN

   update User  set userPicture = (SELECT  BulkColumn
        FROM Openrowset(Bulk '''+ @imagepath +''', Single_Blob) as img) , userEmail = @userEmail, userPhone = @userPhone, userAdress = @userAdress where userId =@UserId
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    INSERT User(
    userId,
    UserName ,
    userPicture
    userEmail,
    userPhone,
    userAdress,
    )
         VALUES (
             @UserId,
    @UserName ,
    (SELECT  BulkColumn
        FROM Openrowset(Bulk '''+ @imagepath +''', Single_Blob) as img),
    @UserEmail,
    @UserPhone,
    @UserAdress)
END
END
```

Comment: `OPENROWSET` requires a literal string. You'll need to use dynamic SQL and ***SAFELY*** (I cannot stress that word enough) inject the value in.

Comment: I can't understand you , can you explain to me please the solution?

Answer (score -1):

As I said in the comment *"`OPENROWSET` requires a literal string. You'll need to use dynamic SQL and **safely** inject the value in."*:

```sql
DECLARE @imagepath nvarchar(255) = N'C:\Temp\YourImage.png', --Obviously you have set elsewhere.
        @Id int = 1; --Obviously you have set elsewhere.

DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX),
        @CRLF nchar(2) = NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10);
SET @SQL = N'INSERT INTO dbo.test(Id, logo)' + @CRLF +
           N'SELECT @Id, BulkColumn' + @CRLF +
           N'FROM OPENROWSET(BULK '''+ REPLACE(@imagepath,'''','''''') +''', SINGLE_BLOB) AS img;';

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL, N'@Id int', @Id; --I have guessed the datatype of @Id
```

---

It seems to OP isn't familiar with how to `CREATE` or `ALTER` a procedure; I must admit I find this odd considering that they have a `CREATE` statement in their question, but nevermind.

To create or alter a procedure you use the `CREATE` or `ALTER` command; in more recent versions there is also `CREATE OR ALTER` as well.

In simple terms it's like this in psuedo SQL:

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER PROC {Your Procedure Name} {Parameters} AS
BEGIN

    {Stored Procedure SQL statements}
END;
```

So, you might want a stored procedure that returns for a specific customer ID; that would be

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROC dbo.GetCustomer @ID int AS
BEGIN

    SELECT CustomerName,
           CustomerEmail,
           CustomerPhone
    FROM dbo.Customer
    WHERE ID = @ID;
END;
```

For what I have you, just do this:

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER PROC  dbo.InsertImage @ID int, @imagepath nvarchar(255) AS
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX),
            @CRLF nchar(2) = NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10);
    SET @SQL = N'INSERT INTO dbo.test(Id, logo)' + @CRLF +
               N'SELECT @Id, BulkColumn' + @CRLF +
               N'FROM OPENROWSET(BULK '''+ REPLACE(@imagepath,'''','''''') +''', SINGLE_BLOB) AS img;';

    EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL, N'@Id int', @Id; --I have guessed the datatype of @Id
```

Comment: I forget to add the complete code, what I have added is a procedure, not an SQL statement.

Comment: Even *if* it's in a Stored Procedure, that doesn't change my answer, @abdou_dev .

Comment: I got an error : " Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'.

Comment: I can't replicate that error, @abdou_dev , the above creates perfectly valid SQL with the same input values; what did you change?#

Comment: I have tested your solution and other solution posted as tuto on the web , but it does not work for me https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4963/simple-image-import-and-export-using-tsql-for-sql-server/ , this solution save to the database null values , I can't understand what's the wrong with SQL Server 2019?

Comment: I have a stored procedure insert to add into a table that contains others columns not only the image column , that's the problem !!

Comment: I don't follow what you mean by that. I ***assumed*** that you at least had the `INSERT` portion of your statement (`INSERT INTO dbo.test(Id, logo)`) correct; I can't be held responsible if that part isn't.

Comment: You are right at this point , I have'nt posted the other parts of my code

Comment: It would be great to hear why this answer isn't helpful from the voter, so I can understand how I can improve it. Thanks.

Comment: I told you that the I'm searching for a stored procedure not for SQL query , if you see my question , the code starting by `create procedure ` , add to that, I'm searching for a solution to insert an image for a table contains other columns ( not a table specified for image , what I mean not a table image that contains image information's )

Comment: *"I told you that the I'm searching for a stored procedure not for SQL query"* Stored Procedures **contain** SQL Queries, @abdou_dev .... YOu show that in your question...

Comment: I would like to use the other definition of the sql query not a dynamic SQL

Comment: You **must** use dynamic SQL, @abdou_dev, from my answer and comment: *"`OPENROWSET `requires a literal string. You'll need to use dynamic SQL and safely inject the value in."*

Comment: I have added an explanation of how to `CREATE` a procedure for you, @abdou_dev as wekll, though I find it difficult to believe you don't know how to create one when you have a `CREATE` in your question. It seems you need to learn what the SQL you have does first as well.

Comment: My problem is not related to the creation a procedure, I have already created the procedure but the problem is how can I use the bulk in the procedure

Comment: I have added a `CREATE OR ALTER` statement for you, @abdou_dev , but if you had simply said "I don't know how to `CREATE` or `ALTER` a stored procedure" instead of telling me you "don't need a SQL query you need a stored procedure" (which makes no sense, as Procedures contains SQL statements) the confusion could have easily been avoided. I do, however, again suggest taking the time to read some basic tutorials on SQL as `ALTER` is a very fundamental part of the language.

Comment: With respect too, I have a knowledge in SQL Procedures , but you don't understand me what I need exactly and I have created my procedure before you add an explanation of " how to create or alter a procedure " , please see update

Comment: Ok thank you for the respect that you give to me This is sure from your good manners